# How to import crypto-js in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, cryptojs, ionic4

I used following npm command to install

```
npm install crypto-js
```

After installing i imported

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

But i am not getting any when i type Crypto. i dont get any IntelliSense.
I have read on some of the posts which says that i need to add

```
npm install --save @types/crypto-js
```

Tried that as well but then i start getting the error on import statement

I will appreciate if someone can guide me what are the steps i need to follow to make this work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to import like this:

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```